# Extending an unbounded dense linear functional

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space over $\mathbb{C}$

Let $V \subset H$ be a dense subspace of $H$

Let $f : V \to \mathbb{C}$ be a unbounded functional linear

My question is:
Is it always possible extend $f$ to $H$ ? (not necessarily bounded)

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by $f:V\to {\bf C}$ being linear if V is merely a dense subset of H? Are you assuming that V is a dense subspace?

Comment: @YemonChoi yes $V$ is a dense subspace, sorry now I edit

Comment: In that case the answer is yes: take a Hamel basis for V and extend it to a Hamel basis for H. Then define your extension of f by setting it to be zero on all the elements of the Hamel basis that do not lie in V. Of course, this is non-constructive and relies on the axiom of choice

Comment: OK @YemonChoi your answer is enough for my problem, thank you a lot.